# tableau show difference between two calculated columns

Tags: tableau-api

[Please See Picture of my Tableau Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1t5T.png)

I simply want to include a new column that shows the difference between 2017SU and 2016SU. Note that each of those two columns are a running sum.

I've tried doing a secondary table calculation but it does not add a new column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution - more work than you would think it should take, but it makes sense when you think about Tableau views your data. I can't see what the full name of you numeric field starting with Seatc ...

Define three calculated fields:

- 2016SU Seatc = `running_sum(sum(if [Stc Term] = "2016SU" then [Seatc...] end))`
- 2017SU Seatc = `running_sum(sum(if [Stc Term] = "2017SU" then [Seatc...] end))`
- diff = `[2017SU Seatc] - [2016SU Seatc]`

You'll have to set the partitioning and addressing (aka compute using) on the table calcs appropriately.

Finally, now you can use Measure Names and Measure Values to build a table (or other chart) using these 3 measures

Comment: This works and now I understand how to think about how Tableau views data. Thank you so much.